# How can I print out the design matrix from lm in R?

Tags: r, linear-regression

Assume x2-x4 are continuous predictors occupying one column each in the design matrix created using lm() in R. I want to include x1 a categorical variable that has 3 levels.

Regression R code:
fit <- lm(y~as.factor(x1)+x2+x3+c4,data=mydata)

How can I print the design matrix from lm() in R and what would it look like? I need to know the default coding used in R so I can write contrast statements properly.

Comment: Here says model.matrix() http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/How-do-I-obtain-the-design-matrix-of-an-lm-td836696.html

Comment: call `res <- lm()` with the argument `x=TRUE` then the design matrix will be returned in the model object `res` Then call `str(res)` to see the structure of `res`, and you will now how to get the design matrix from it.  But easier is to call `model.matrix(y ~ x + f, data=...)` with the same model formula you use in `lm`.

Answer (score 5):

I think the `model.matrix()` function is what you're after.

As [kjetil b halvorsen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52908038/how-can-i-print-out-the-design-matrix-from-lm-in-r/52908041#comment92726780_52908038) says you can specify the model in the argument. Or you can just hand `model.matrix` the defined model.

```
fit <- lm(y~as.factor(x1)+x2+x3+c4,data=mydata)
model.matrix(fit)
```

You can even get a design matrix for new data: `model.matrix(fit, data=newdata)`

Answer (score 0):

The [comment by kjetil b halvorsen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52908038/how-can-i-print-out-the-design-matrix-from-lm-in-r/52908041#comment92726780_52908038) helped me the most:

> call `res <- lm()` with the argument `x=TRUE` then the design matrix will be returned in the model object `res` Then call `str(res)` to see the structure of `res`, and you will now how to get the design matrix from it.  But easier is to call `model.matrix(y ~ x + f, data=...)` with the same model formula you use in `lm`.